# How to store machine learning trained model in Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a trained model, trained on IMDB reviews. I have to classify 10 reviews * 3 times, means 30 reviews. It takes more or less 3 min to classify 10 reviews, so it will take around 10 minutes to classify all reviews. In that time, user will just go away, so I read somewhere to store model in Redis. I have researched a bit but can't find anything. Can anyone please help me in storing trained model in Redis?

Comment: Not sure it will fit your needs, but look at this: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redis-ml

Comment: nope, it doesn't fit my need :(